# Changing point size in Show

Tags: graphics

Suppose that `a` is a line plot produced with `Plot`, and `b` and `c` are scatterplots produced with `ListPlot`.

Furthermore, suppose that `Show[a, b, c]` produces this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How can I modify the expression `Show[a, b, c]` so that the directive `PointSize[Tiny]` is applied to the points coming from `b` and `c`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe this `/. PointSize[x_] -> PointSize[.02]`

```
dat1 = Transpose[Sort /@ RandomReal[1, {2, 50}]];
dat2 = Transpose[Sort /@ RandomReal[1, {2, 50}]];

Show[
  Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> 2],
  ListPlot[dat1, PlotStyle -> 1],
  ListPlot[dat2, PlotStyle -> 2]] /. PointSize[x_] -> PointSize[.02]
```

[image]

Comment: What about the thickness of line in show? Thanks!